# Yet another Least Squares matrix derivation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I understand the solution to the well known Least squares as explained in the following post

[Least-squares solution to a matrix equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354736/least-squares-solution-to-a-matrix-equation)

We solve for β so that below expression has minimal value.

$\mathbf(Y−Xβ)′ × (Y−Xβ)$

In above, lets assume that we have N samples each with D features

- Y is N*1
- X is N*D
- β is D*1

I am wondering how the derivation steps would change had we assumed Y output shape is 1 * N

- Y is N*1

So the equation for Y would be

$\mathbf Y = β'X'$

and not

$\mathbf  Y = Xβ $

as in the original derivation.

Again, while I completely understand the steps in the original derivation, I could not solve if I had assumed  Y = β′X′

$\mathbf  (Y−β′X′)′×(Y−β′X′)$

Expanding the above for derivative wrt β yields below  - but I couldn't proceed further

$\mathbf  Y′Y  − Y′β′X′ - XβY - Xββ′X′ $

For academic interest, I like to understand if it at all possible to solve for β this route and the steps

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: You can use the linked solution by replacing $Y$ by its transpose, i.e. the same substitution you've made in the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks. Specifically, what are the derivative of terms  Y'β'X'  and XβY wrt β   (I can't get a dimensionally compatible value for these terms.  I may be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In brief, the steps to solve a least squares problem are 
$$\eqalign{
y &= X\beta \quad\implies
\min_\beta\,\|X\beta-y\|^2 \quad\implies
\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty \\
}$$
The decision to use $Y=y^T$ instead of $y$ 
has **no effect** on these steps, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
Y^T &= X\beta \quad\implies
\min_\beta\,\|X\beta-Y^T\|^2 \quad\implies
\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY^T \\
}$$
The approach can be summarized as:

$\quad$Substitute the new $Y^T$ variable where ever the original $y$ variable appears.

Make this substitution in every expression, every formula, and every *derivative*.